# How to restrict read and write permissions of Java Application

Tags: java, permissions

Currently I am creating a playground for a programming language (pl).
The code entered in the playground is remotly executed on a server.

The pl runs in the Java VM and is executed in a docker container.
Since you can read and write to files in the pl I need to take away these permissions from the Java application that executes the code.

I am executing the Java app like this:

```
java -cp path/to/app.jar "app.package.main" -x "place code here"
```

How can I remove the read and write permissions from a Java application?

Comment: what read and write permissions are we talking about?

Comment: reading and writing to any file. The java application should not be able to read or write to any files.

Comment: since a Java application can only do what the programmer intended/coded it to do, don't provide code that can read files or write to them, or, only for certain roles

Comment: I get your point, but the jar file for the programming language is fixed. I did not develope it myself, the author of the pl did.

Comment: If you are running untrusted code, it does not matter what language you believe the code is written in. Just make sure the **user** executing the code is not capable of doing whatever you don't want the program to be able to do. This is an OS/FileSystem permissions issue, not a java issue. (Hint: writing files is not the only potentially dangerous thing a program can do - executing other programs, reading information it should not see, sending emails, etc... can be problems too, for example)

Comment: then either check the documentation whether it is possible, ask the author or alter the code (if you have permission to do so)

Comment: @Hulk The code is executed by a restricted user, but since this user also has to execute Java itself, he needs read and write permissions to some files (which means they can also be altered or read by the remote code)

Comment: @Stultuske Altering the code might be possible but then I would have to apply the changes to every new version of the pl and recompile it.

Comment: Execute and write permisions are different things and should probably not be held by the same user in such a scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a custom Security Manager configuration as a parameter:

```
java -Djava.security.manager
```

BUT: this does not mean the program will work, because if something is forbidden an

> AccessControlException

is thrown and the program will crash, or at least (most likely) behave differently.

See this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour2/step2.html

The better solution is probably to get the code and alter it to fit your needs (only if the licensing allows this of course).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will give it a try